# font-weight only changing between normal and bold, regardless of imprted values

Tags: html, css, angular, fonts

I'm importing Inter font-face from Google Fonts, like this:

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap";
```

Meaning, that I should have all the font-weights from 300 all the way to 800, but instead what is happening, is the browser either renders normal, or bold of this font, even when I'm changing the property from Chrome Dev Tools.
In the Network tab I can see all the listed weights fetched from google, so the import in fact works.

I've tried using the old import method for Google Fonts, removing all font-weight references from my global styles.scss, but nothing seems solving this.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you replace the semicolons with commas it seems to be OK.

Comment: @AHaworth this line for import is straight from Google Fonts, I don't think commas would be the problem, especially because even if I only import let's say 900, I still get normal and bold only.